# ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_kernel'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When i try to use tensorflow to train model, i get this error message.

File "/Users/ABC/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py", line 7, in 
    from .conv_utils import convert_kernel

ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_kernel'

i have already install Keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. The filename of my python code was "tensorflow.py". After I changed the name to "test.py". The issue was resolved.

I guess there is already a "tensorflow.py" in the tensorflow package. If anyone uses the same name, it may lead to the conflict.

If your python code is also called "tensorflow.py", you can try to use other names and see if it helps.